# How to deal with multiple usage of a React-Intl message?

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I can't find anything in the `react-intl` docs (I'm using `v2` branch) regarding this kind of usage, hence this issue. Is there a recommended approach for the following use-case?

Say I have 2 components, `Tooltip` and `Select`. Both require the same i18n-formatted string, say something like:

```
<FormattedMessage
    id='ui.widget.cycleOffsetSelector.timeCycle.label'
    defaultMessage="This {cycle}"
    values={{cycle: props.cycle}}
/>
```

How do I use the same message in the other component? Just using this:

```
<FormattedMessage
    id='ui.widget.cycleOffsetSelector.timeCycle.label'
    values={{cycle: props.cycle}}
/>
```

does not work (should not :) ). So, what is the correct way to do this?
Do I have to keep these shared messages somewhere globally in my app? Because it can become cumbersome maintaining a list of "shared" intl messages separate from the code, the very thing which `react-intl` claims to solve.

Comment: Is this v1 or v2 of react-intl?

Comment: v2. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you could always use the [`formatMessage()`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/master/src/format.js#L102-L189) function directly, as per the [guide](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#update-formatmessage-calls).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In react-intl v2 the message ids are static so no 2 ids can be alike. The thought is to keep assets that are being used in the components in the same file for easy development. Then extract the strings at build time for translation. Many times this problem can be solved by creating a higher order component (HOC) or creating a component to reuse instead of reusing a message string.

If creating a HOC is not an option here are a few more ways to handle this issue:

---

You can use [defineMessages()](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#definemessages) in a centralized messages file to define common strings that you reuse, keeping strings that are only for specific components in those components.

---

Namespacing ids is also a possibility.

> ui.widget.cycleOffsetSelector.timeCycle.select.label
>   ui.widget.cycleOffsetSelector.timeCycle.tooltip.label

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'd already centralized the common strings into a shared location. That is the best approach for development, and is much easier to refactor.